# await fetch in flask not getting required return

Tags: javascript, python, flask, asynchronous, http-post

I'm trying to use await fetch in JS to use a function that I created in Flask.
My code for the JS is:

```
let dictionary = await fetch("/getName");
let user_name = await dictionary.name;
```

and my code in flask is:

```
@app.route("/getName")
def getName():
    output = {"name": ""}
    print("hello")
    if NAME_KEY in session:
        output["name"] = session[NAME_KEY]
        print(output)
    return jsonify(output)
```

why does this not work?
to be specific to causes the website to have a 400 bad request.

I removed the await feature from both of the variables, and instead it creates the error:

> 'Request' object has no attribute 'is_xhr'

I downgraded werkzeug to 0.16.1, and no nothing just shows up. There aren't any errors, but nothing comes and nothing gets printed by the system.
Here is my new code for JS. (Flask stays the same)

```
let dictionary = fetch("/getName");
console.log("start");
console.log(dictionary);
let user_name = dictionary.name;
```

Comment: If the answer below doesn't work then I would edit your question adding a bit more code/context that shows how your await code is being called.

Comment: @Luke thanks a lot, your suggestion down below works perfectly! if possible can you send me the webpage / videos that help me understand why stuff like this is required?

Comment: The short (too simplistic) answer is that JavaScript doesn't wait for one line of code to finish executing before executing the next. This is a problem because there are two common situations (DB queries and Web API calls) when it takes a while for a line of code to complete, but when you want it to complete before executing the next line of code.  To ensure that JS code does execute in an ordered sequence there are various techniques you can use. These include using async and await, or callbacks, or promises or the ".then" syntax which is popular when using fetch.

Comment: As an aside (and this is just my opinion) JavaScript is celebrated because of the fact that it doesn't wait for one line of code to execute before executing the next. Supposedly it makes things faster.  But I think that behavior is overrated because it introduces all these complications and associated techniques that aren't needed in most other languages.  For example, when making a DB call in the Flask/Python environment you won't see any of the above await/async techniques being used. The code just executes in an intuitive step by step fashion.  Javascript's convolutions are totally avoided.

Comment: @Luke hmm sounds interesting, however if it does truly make a big difference to performance then it should be "celebrated". Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you haven't wrapped the await code inside a function that has been declared with async.  Or you have declared the async function incorrectly.  This example works:

Your Flask view/route:

```
@app.route('/getName')
def get_name():
    print("in getName view....")
    output = {"name": ""}
    return jsonify(output)
```

Your client side code calling the above /getName route:

```
<head>
    <title>REST</title>
    <script>
        const getName =  async () => {
                try {
                    const response = await fetch('/getName')
                    const resp = await response.json();
                    console.log("Obj returned from server", resp)
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log('Fetch error: ', error);
                }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="getName()">getName</button>
</body>
```

For a full working example (e.g. including a Flask app.py file and a Flask template) see:

https://github.com/lfernandez55/REST-auth/tree/stack-overflow-67606023

Comment: This Jsbin also demos how you can make a fetch GET call using the then syntax, or alternatively, using the await syntax you are working with: https://jsbin.com/ciziyar/edit?html,js,console,output .

Comment: Also,  in my experience the fetch .then syntax is more popular than using fetch with await.  If you want to see your fetch example using then rather than await,  look back one commit in the above branch.

Answer (score 0):

Decoupling the `javascript` code from `html` (for searching the input user name in session dictionary), the above code can be broken into the following 3 files, making the code for the `flask` app a little more modular (with the following folder structure):

[image]

```
## app.py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template
import os 

# initialization
app = Flask(__name__)

# Route for handling session search
@app.route('/get_name', methods=["POST"])
def get_name():
    session_dict = {'coder', 'dev', 'test'} ## dummy dictionary as placeholder
    user_name = request.json["user_name"]  # Get the user input from the request
    print(f"checking if {user_name} is in session...")
    exists = f"{user_name} exists in session" if user_name in session_dict else f"{user_name} does not exist in session"
    output = {"name": exists}
    return jsonify(output)
    
# Routes for the home page
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index.html")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")  # Render the index.html template
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
// app.js
const form = document.getElementById("rest-form");
const user_input = document.getElementById("user-name");
const response_elem = document.getElementById("name-exists");

form.addEventListener("submit", async (event) => {

    event.preventDefault();

    const user_input_value = user_input.value.trim();
    if (!user_input_value) {
        return;
    }

    try {
          const resp = await fetch("/get_name", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ user_name: user_input_value })
          });
          const response_data = await resp.json();
          if (resp.ok) {
            const chat_response = response_data.name;
            response_elem.value = chat_response;
          } else {
            alert("Error when fetching response");
          }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Fetch error: ', error);
        alert(error)
    }
    
 });
```

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Fetch Demo</title>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Fetch Demo</h1>
        <form id="rest-form" >
          <div class="input-group">
            <label for="user-name">User-Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="user-name" name="user-name">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
           <label for="name-exists">Response:</label>
           <input type="text" id="name-exists" name="name-exists" readonly>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" id="submit-button">Fetch</button>
        </form>
        <script src="static/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The next animation shows the demo, note that the dummy users `coder`, `dev`, `test` are already present in the demo `session dictionary`, hence searching them with `await fetch` succeeds (and the corresponding text is displayed in the response text box).

Also, notice that the `POST` method is used for the route `get_name`. While defining the Event listener for the `submit` button the `event` is wrapped with the `async` keyword in `javascript` code.

[image]